# How to use a glob pattern for a location attribute of a property?

Tags: ant, properties, design-patterns

I want to set a property to a filename, for which I know a pattern that will match a unique file. For example, I have the file:

> plugins/doc.en_20110608.zip

I define in my ant file:

`<property name="doc.zip" location="plugins/doc.en_*.zip" />`

I know the pattern will match only one file. The problem is that ant doesn't try to match any pattern at this point, and fails because there is no file named `plugins/doc.en_*.zip`.

If I'm not using a *fileset*, it's because the property can be substituted where a *fileset* is not allowed, like *destfile* attribute of *zip* task.

`<zip destfile="${doc.zip}" update="true"> ... </zip>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no I think, but you can use [reference/path shortcuts](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#pathshortcut) to 'stringify' a fileset into a property.  Something like:

```
<fileset id="doc.zip.fs" dir="plugins" includes="doc.en_*.zip"/>
<property name="doc.zip" value="${toString:doc.zip.fs}" />
```

Comment: Just a warning: the property doc.zip contains only the filename, not the full location. Use location="plugins/${toString:doc.zip.fs}" instead.